# Prevent Outlook autodiscover wizard from filling the email address

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, autodiscovery

I would like to prevent outlook from filling the email address field in the auto account setup wizard when domain joined.

An example of my scenario is described here:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/kristinw/archive/2013/04/19/controlling-outlook-autodiscover-behavior.aspx

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A registry key is available, solution here : http://www.dotnetmikael.com/2015/02/outlook-profiles-prevent-account-setup.html

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that.

Comment: Actually yes, see my answer